# User input data handling function

Tags: python

I'm working in project bikeshare for udacity, during project review, I received the following comment regarding my function for user input handling.

> Inputs not handled correctly

> Data could not be loaded properly. Could you please change the input process so examples looking as follows are accepted?:
> washington, january, monday
> barcelona, WaSHINGTON, january, MonDAY (in this example, the first introduced city is rejected because it's not among the choosable ones)
> washington, jUNe, mOnDAy
> washington, March, Tuesday
> washington, aLL, All

> Please, notice how input handling must be case insensitive (both washington and WasHingTON should be accepted). As a suggestion, I would recommend you to transform the input written by the user using the 'lower' function. This transformation will allow you to accept as valid all the different inputs you should expect given the rubrics especifications: washington, Washington, WaSHINgton, WASHINGTON...

> When reviewing these inputs, please make sure you don't only test get_filters, but also you pass the returned values to load_data. This way you'll be able to ensure the whole process works as expected.

what I do not understand is that I'm already handling those issues.

Here is my code

```py
def get_filters():
    """
    Asks user to specify a city, month, and day to analyze.

    Returns:
        (str) city - name of the city to analyze
        (str) month - name of the month to filter by, or "all" to apply no month filter
        (str) day - name of the day of week to filter by, or "all" to apply no day filter
    """
    print("\n")
    print('Hello! Let\'s explore some US bikeshare data!')
    # TO DO: get user input for city (chicago, new york city, washington). HINT: Use a while loop to handle invalid inputs
    while True:
        print("\n")
        # Taking user input & turning to lower case to avoid alternative case inputs
        city= input("Please enter desierd city name (Chicago, New york city or Washington cities) ").lower()
        print("\n")
        # Checking if the entered city name is identical to one of the loaded cities' names
        if city=="chicago" or city=="new york city" or city=="washington":
           print("\n")
           # If user input is identical to one of the loaded cities' names, print a confirmation message & break the loop
           print("[",city,"]","selected.")
           print("\n")
           break
        else:
          # If user input is not identical to one of the loaded cities'names, print an alarm message & repeat the loop to get user input
           print("Icorrect entry, pleae check spelling & enter again.")
           print("\n")
    # Initializing default value for NO Filter
    month=""
    # Initializing default value for NO Filter
    day=""
    while True:
        # 1st. step filter, to get feedback from user to filter by month, day, or not to filter
        print("\n")
        filter= input("Would you like to filter the data by month, day, or not at all? Type \"none\" for no time filter.").lower()
        print("\n")
        # Chceking user input limits
        if filter=="month" or filter=="day" or filter=="none":
           print("[",filter,"]"," filter selected")
           break
        else:
           print("Icorrect entry, pleae check spelling & enter again")
           print("\n")
    if filter!="none":
        # 2nd Step filter, if usere chose to filter, ask user to enter month filter(month name or "all")
        if filter=="month":
            # TO DO: get user input for month (all, january, february, ... , june)
            while True:
                # Taking user input & turning to lower case to avoid alternative case inputs
                print("\n")
                month= input("Which month? All, January, February, March, April, May, or June?").lower()
                # Checking if the entered month is identical to one of the loaded months' names or "all"
                if month=="all" or month=="january" or month=="february" or month=="march" or month=="april" or month=="may" or month=="june":
                   print("\n")
                   # If user input is identical to one of the loaded months' names or "all", print a confirmation message & break the loop
                   print("[",month,"]"," seleced.")
                   print("\n")
                   break
                else:
                   # If user input is not identical to one of the loaded months' names or "all", print an alarm message & repeat the loop to get user input
                   print("Icorrect entry, pleae check spelling & enter again.")
                   print("\n")
        # 2nd Step filter, if usere chose to filter, ask user to enter day filter(day name or "all")
        elif filter=="day":
            # TO DO: get user input for day of week (all, monday, tuesday, ... sunday)
            while True:
                # Taking user input & turning to lower case to avoid alternative case inputs
                print("\n")
                day= input("Which day? All, Su, Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, or Sa?").lower()
                # Checking if the entered day is identical to one of the loaded days' names or "all"
                if day=="all" or day=="su" or day=="mo" or day=="tu" or day=="we" or day=="th" or day=="fr" or day=="sa":
                   print("\n")
                   # If user input is identical to one of the loaded days' names or "all", print a confirmation message & break the loop
                   print("[",day,"]"," seleced.")
                   print("\n")
                   break
                else:
                   # If user input is not identical to one of the loaded months' days or "all", print an alarm message & repeat the loop to get user input
                   print("Icorrect entry, pleae check spelling & enter again.")
                   print("\n")


    print('-'*40)
    # Return data inputs of city name, month & day
    return city, month, day
```

Could you please support me where is the problem in my code?
Thanks

Comment: Are you able to respond to this response? We aren't Udacity support, and everyone reviews code differently and maybe they missed you using lower function at the same line as input rather than separate variable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what was original description? Which part of code you got at start? Maybe it needs to return original text like `WaSHINgton`